# Lippmann-Schwinger equation and Scattering amplitude with spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

How does the Lippmann-Schwinger equation and the scattering amplitude generalize when we include spin? Also, how does the scattering amplitude up to the first Born approximation change if we include spin?

EDIT: If somebody could include the scattering amplitude with spin, it would be ideal. Also, I know that the form of these will be the same if we include spin(the state ket now being a tensor product of the spatial ket and the spin ket), I am just confused on putting the spin ket for the states corresponding to before and after the scattering

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned already, the Lippmann-Schwinger equation have the same form whether you include spin or not:
$$
|\Psi_\alpha^\pm\rangle=|\Phi_\alpha\rangle+(E_\alpha+H_0\pm i\epsilon)^{-1}V|\Psi^\pm_\alpha\rangle
$$
or, in integrated form (using a complete set of free states),
$$
|\Psi_\alpha^\pm\rangle=|\Phi_\alpha\rangle+\int\mathrm d\beta\ \frac{\langle\Phi_\beta|V|\Psi_\alpha^\pm\rangle|\Phi_\beta\rangle}{E_\alpha-E_\beta\pm i\epsilon}
$$

Here, $\alpha$ is a collection of parameters that label the states. These may or may not include spin, depending on the context.

The Born approximation corresponds to taking $|\Psi^\pm_\alpha\rangle\approx |\Phi_\alpha\rangle$ inside the integral, so that
$$
|\Psi_\alpha^\pm\rangle=|\Phi_\alpha\rangle+\int\mathrm d\beta\ \frac{\langle\Phi_\beta|V|\Phi_\alpha^\pm\rangle|\Phi_\beta\rangle}{E_\alpha-E_\beta\pm i\epsilon}+\mathcal O(V^2)
$$

The first correction thus corresponds to the matrix element
$$
\langle\Phi_\beta|V|\Phi_\alpha^\pm\rangle
$$

If we consider the one-particle problem, where the labels are the position and spin, we can use the basis $|\boldsymbol x,\pm\rangle$, so that
$$
\langle\Phi_\beta|V|\Phi_\alpha^\pm\rangle=\sum_{s,s'}\int\mathrm d\boldsymbol x\,\mathrm d\boldsymbol y\ \langle\Phi_\beta|\boldsymbol x,s\rangle\langle \boldsymbol x,s|V|\boldsymbol y,s'\rangle\langle \boldsymbol y,s'|\Phi_\alpha^\pm\rangle
$$
and I guess you can take it from here.

For more details, see Weinberg's book, Vol.I, chapter 3.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific before, but my main problem is about how to write $
|\Psi_\alpha^\pm\rangle$, $|\Phi_\alpha^\pm\rangle$ and $|\Phi_\beta\rangle$ as a tensor product of a spatial and spin part.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan as usual, $|\varphi\rangle=|\varphi_+\rangle|+\rangle+|\varphi_-\rangle|-\rangle$.

Comment: I can't follow you, sorry.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan let $\varphi_\pm$ be the spatial part, and let $|\pm\rangle$ be the standard "up/down" states. Then $|\varphi\rangle=|\varphi_+\rangle\otimes|+\rangle+|\varphi_-\rangle\otimes|-\rangle$, or, in terms of wavefunctions, $\varphi(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\varphi_+(x)\\ \varphi_-(x)\end{pmatrix}$. I don't know how to put it more explicitly than this :-P

Comment: I understand the reason you are writing $|\phi\rangle$ in this way but I am confused by the following: $|\Psi_\alpha^\pm\rangle$ is the final wavefunction we get after the scattering so I'll denote its spin part as $|s, m\rangle$ . $|\Phi_\alpha\rangle$ is the wavefunction before the scattering(the incident wavefunction), so I'l write its spin part as $|s', m'\rangle$. So, now I have denoted the spin part of the incident wavefunction(that is a known) and of the final wavefunction(want to find it). So, the problem is how should I write the spin part of $|\Phi_\beta\rangle$?

Comment: This confusion of mine came up while doing an exercise containing scattering with spin. So, it would be ideal if you have the time to briefly continue this discussion in a chat room.

Comment: would you mind? (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58381/discussion-on-question-lippmann-schwinger-equation-and-scattering-amplitude-with)

Comment: Hi @TheQuantumMan, you can usually find me in the main chat, [the h-bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). You are welcome to join me there whenever you want, but I'm afraid I don't think I will be able to say anything that I haven't said already.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lippman-Schwinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation) can be used to perturbatively expand the scattering solutions of a *potential scattering problem*. The Born approximation is the truncation of the expansion at linear order in the potential.

So you have a particle scattering off a potential. If you include spin nothing changes at all. Physically your potential might be spin dependent and change, but that is all.

In quantum mechanics, which is the context of the Lippman-Schwinger equation spin enters through (anti-)symmetrization of the multi-particle wavefunction under particle exchange. Note that the Lippman-Schwinger equation is explicitly constructed for potential scattering and may [only be used to deal with two-body scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation#Usage). For three particle scattering there are the [Faddeev equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev_equations).

Comment: Can you give the equation mathematically?

Comment: @TheQuantumMan what I was trying to say is that the Lippman-Schwinger equation should not change if you include spin. I can give the standard Lippman-Schwinger equation if you'd like?

Comment: What I am really confused about is how to include the Born approximation(with spins) in the Lippman-Schwinger equation with spins. In particular, I am confused on which spin ket or bra to put on each side of the equation(spin after the scattering or before). So, if you could mathematically clarify this point, it would be highley appreciated

Comment: @TheQuantumMan now I am confused, I might have misinterpreted the question. could you maybe state the actual problem you have at hand?

Comment: I want to solve a scattering problem using the first Born approximation. In the problem, I have the scatterers and the particle beam that we send to them. All of them have s=0.5. I need to find the scattering amplitude. So, I need to tweak the standard Lippman-Schwinger anf Born approximation to include spin. But, the scattering amplitude in its standard form is analogous to <k'|V|Ψ> and both <k'| and |Ψ> refer to the case of AFTER the scattering, this confuses me when I try to generalize it to include spin. Now, the first-order Born approximation without spin reads |Ψ>=|k> with |k> being the

Comment: unscattered beam. So, if I assign spins to the first Born approximation I get |Ψ>|spin after>=|k>|spin before>. What I have trouble generalizing to the case with spin is the scattering amplitude. That is why I needed the L-S equation with spin. So, I can work it out all the way up to the scattering amplitude. Hope I did not confuse you, which is highly likely

Comment: @TheQuantumMan does your 'potential' have spin cross-scattering terms? In most potential scattering problems I know the potential just acts on the spatial part of the wavefunction. In that case spin would completely decouple and you could just ignore it.

Comment: V=(Yukawa potential for the spatial part)*$\vec{\sigma_1}\dot{}\vec{\sigma_2}$ where "1" stands for the incident particles and "2" for the scatterer particles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58307/discussion-between-wolpertinger-and-thequantumman).